# How to set string at a particular index to a textview

Tags: java, android

How to set string at a particular index to a textview.
The below code is not working for me.

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String[] picname ={"abc","def"};
String data=picname[0];
t1.setText(data);
```

[image]

Comment: what is not working? are you getting an exception? if so please post the stacktrace

Comment: yes getting exception.

Comment: okay. add it to your question. it will help us solve your problem

Comment: Another part is remaining from the above comment "if so please post the stacktrace"

Comment: Probably you need put this code in 'runOnUiThread()' method

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
int position = 1; // Position on EditText
Editable etext = t1.getText(); // getText() Optional
Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
```

Comment: He's not using a Editable though.. appears to be using a TextView

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
 String name = "data number"  

String[] firstname = name.split(" "); 
String first_Name = firstname[0];
String last_Name = firstname[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the text on the ui thread.

```
private void updateText()
{
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
   {
        public void run() 
        {
              TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              String[] picname ={"abc","def"};
              String data=picname[0];
              t1.setText(data);
        }
   });     
}
```